# Bulk move sub-subfolders to sub-sub-subfolders with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory-structure

I have several sub-subfolders that I'd like to move to another sub-subfolder, so they become sub-sub-subfolders. In other words, what I have now is:

```
F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\

F:\Doe, Jane\A Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\A Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\A Files\3 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\B Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\B Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\B Files\3 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive

F:\Public, John Q\A Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\A Files\2 Filesfile1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\A Files\3 Filesfile1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\B Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\B Files\2 Filesfile1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\B Files\3 Filesfile1.docx
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\A Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\A Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\A Files\3 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\B Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\B Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Doe, Jane\Archive\B Files\3 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\A Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\A Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\A Files\3 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\B Files\1 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\B Files\2 Files\file1.docx

F:\Public, John Q\Archive\B Files\3 Files\file1.docx
```

I'm thinking PowerShell should work but I'm far from an expert; I did manage to bulk rename the sub-subfolders but that was a year ago and I've forgotten most of what I learned then.

I tried this (with a test folder):

```
$source = "F:Test\*\Client Uploads\"
$destination = "F:Test\*\Archive\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory | 
    Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose
```

But I get this error:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: F:\Test\Doe, Jane\Client Uploads Destination:
F:\Test\*\Archive\".
Move-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:5 char:5
+     Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (F:\Test\Doe, Jane\Client Uploads:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], Argu
   mentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

It looks like maybe the * in the destination is the problem, I can't find the right terms to search to make the * in the source create the same name as the * in the destination.

Comment: It's too ambiguous. I would just use a loop

Comment: Any thoughts on how that might look? I have looked at info on loops but I'm not getting it.